# Git show closets tag + count of commits after that tag

Tags: git

How can Git describe current HEAD in the following format: `7.x-1.0-beta2+15` ?
Where `7.x-1.0-beta2` is the closest tag name and `15` is the count of commits from that tag to the current head.

Currently I use the following alias combined from the commands I found on StackOverflow:

```
alias gv='echo $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)+$(git rev-list  `git rev-list --tags --no-walk --max-count=1`..HEAD --count)'
```

(means "Git show version")

But I'm not sure if it's a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Git's [describe](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) command does this. To invoke it, simply run `git describe`.

From the documentation:

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit. If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown. Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit.

The displayed string will have the format `<tag>-<number of commits after tag>-g<current commit's id>`

Comment: Does not work for me: `git clone http://git.drupal.org/project/date_facets.git && cd date_facets && git checkout 9037608 && git describe`

Comment: @Leksat. Try adding `--all` to the `git describe` command - by default it only uses annotated tags

Comment: please try yourself first, and compare results with my request.

Comment: Oops, sorry! `--all` makes use of all refs. The correct command is `--tags`